# How to effectively put data from X,Y,RGB_COLOR_INT pandas dataframe into image-like canvas numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, image, numpy

I have pandas dataframe like this:

|  | x | y | color |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 826 | 1048 | 52416 |
| 1 | 583 | 1031 | 9745407 |
| 2 | 1873 | 558 | 6970623 |
| 3 | 1627 | 255 | 40618 |
| 4 | 49 | 1478 | 9745407 |
| 5 | 408 | 1863 | 14986239 |
| 6 | 111 | 1582 | 9745407 |
| 7 | 1334 | 1840 | 6970623 |
| 8 | 1908 | 1854 | 6970623 |

and numpy array which acts like a image canvas with shape `(width, height, 4)`, pandas X and Y are within the width and height range of the canvas array.

**What would be an effective way to split the RGBA integer values into it's respective channels and then put these into canvas as denoted by it's X,Y?**

---

Currently I was able to separate the RGBA with numpy like this:

```py
np_data = dataframe.to_numpy(np.uint32)
rgb_channels = np_data[:, 2].view(np.uint8).reshape(np_data[:, 2].shape[0], 4)
```

but I was unable to apply the values effectively thru numpy:

```py
# This does not work
np.put(canvas, ((np_data[:, 0] * canvas.shape[0]) + (np_data[:, 1]), rgb_channels)
# I guess rgb_channels would have to have same size as canvas, as the index is applied to both (?) instead of the value argument being consumed for each index
```

The only way that works is this in python:

```py
i = 0 # couldn't make enumerate or numpy.ndenumerate work properly
for x, y in np_data[:, [0, 1]]: # loop thru X,Y coordinates 
     canvas[x][y] = rgb_channels[i]
```

Comment: `(width, height, 4)` => shouldn't it be `RGBA`?

Comment: @QuangHoang Yes, you are right, edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach would go something like this:

```
np_data = (df['color'].to_numpy()
             .astype('uint32')        # uint32
             .view('uint8')           # convert to uint8
             .reshape(len(df), -1)    # reshape 
          )

# new image
canvas = np.zeros((10,10,4), dtype='uint8')

# slicing
canvas[df['x'], df['y']] = np_data
```

I would parse the channels explicitly like this

```
# use [3,2,1,0] if you are working with RGBA
powers = 256 ** np.array([2,1,0])

colors = (df.color.to_numpy()[:,None] & (powers*255))// powers

out = np.zeros((10,10,3), dtype='uint8')
out[df['x'], df['y']] = colors
```